# How Does Android LiveData get() syntax work?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I understand the [need for creating getter and setter points](https://gist.github.com/humblehacker/0eb6458b1df6cf3049e031f36f0615f5) for LiveData in the ViewModel, but I'm looking to understand how the `get()` syntax works in Android.

ie:

```
val isRealtime: LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = _isRealtime
private val _isRealtime = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
```

Comment: Yes, but it's been a couple of years. I'll check that out. Thanks for the tip @MarcinOrlowski!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`get()` is not related to Android.

```
val isRealtime: LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = _isRealtime
```

Here, `get()` is overriding the automatically-generated Kotlin getter function for the `isRealtime` property. So, instead of returning its own value, it returns the value of `_isRealtime`.

Personally, I recommend simpler syntax:

```
private val _isRealtime = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val isRealtime: LiveData<Boolean> = _isRealtime
```

The objective of either of these is to keep the mutability private, so consumers of this class do not accidentally update the `MutableLiveData` themselves.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the simpler syntax @CommonsWare! It's good to know I don't need to explicitly state the `get()`.

Comment: @AdamHurwitz: `get()` has its uses, but for more complex scenarios. For example, one pattern in Android is to create private extension properties on `Intent` for extras or on `Bundle` for fragment arguments. There, you would override `get()` and `set()` on the extension properties to route to the proper getters/setters (e.g., `getString()` and `putString()` on a `Bundle`). For a simple case like this, though, that seems like overkill.

Comment: Also, an organizational advantage of keeping `get()` is it allows you to define all of the public variables at the top of the `ViewModel` class.

Comment: Why would anyone accidentally setvalue for a livedata when they know the architecture they are doing?

Comment: @Harsha: Bugs happen.

Comment: So you're saying that maybe a junior developer may get the code and probably mess with it.. So the solution is to copy that value to a regular livedata object and return that in the getter method instead?

Comment: @Harsha: There is no copying in either of the options in my answer.

Comment: Oh, I'm a Java developer, so couldn't grasp the Kotlin. So the MutableLiveData object is being upcasted to a LiveData in here?

Comment: @Harsha: "So the MutableLiveData object is being upcasted to a LiveData in here?" -- correct.

Comment: Wouldn't not adding the `get()` will create an extra variable in the generated bytecode?

Comment: @PramodGarg: I believe that it is optimized away by the compiler, and even if it is not, it it not a significant cost. FWIW, I think Kotlin 1.8.0 has a built-in option for this sort of type-shadowing.

Comment: Could you please share a ref article on compiler optimizing this, if you have it handy?

Answer (score 8):

In Kotlin we have multiple ways of exposing live data from ViewModel to the view.

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {

    // Solution 1 - make MutableLiveData public
    // This approach works, but this is a bad idea because
    // view can modify the LiveData values
    val liveDataA1 = MutableLiveData<State>()

    // Solution 2 - let's make LiveData public (expose it instead of MutableLiveData)
    // Now from view perspective this solution looks fine, bu we have a problem,
    // because we need MutableLiveData within ViewModel to put/post new values to
    // the stream (we can't post values to LiveData).
    val liveDataA2 = MutableLiveData<State>() as LiveData<State>

    // Let's capture our requirements:
    // 1. We need to expose (immutable) LiveData to the view,
    // so it cannot edit the data itself.
    // 2. We need to access MutableLiveData from ViewModel to put/post new values.
    // Now, let's consider few appropriate solutions

    // Solution 3
    // Let's name mutable live data using underscore prefix
    private val _liveData3 = MutableLiveData<State>()
    val liveData3 = _liveData3 as LiveData<State>

    // Solution 4
    // We can also perform casting by specifying type for a variable
    // (we can do it because MutableLiveData extends LiveData)
    private val _liveData4 = MutableLiveData<State>()
    val liveData4: LiveData<State> = _liveData4

    // Solution 5
    // Starting from Kotlin 1.4-M.2 we can delegate call to another property
    private val _liveData5 = MutableLiveData<State>()
    val liveData5 by this::_liveData5

    // Solution 6
    // These above solutions work quite well, but we could do even better by
    // defining custom asLiveData extension function.
    private val _liveData6 = MutableLiveData<State>()
    val liveData6 = _liveData6.asLiveData()

    fun <T> MutableLiveData<T>.asLiveData() = this as LiveData<T>
    // Amount of code is similar, but notice that this approach works much better
    // with code completion.

    // Solution 7 (IMO Best)
    // We can also use alternative naming convention - use "mutableLiveData"
    // as variable for mutable live data instead of using underscore prefix
    private val mutableLiveData7 = MutableLiveData<State>()
    val liveData7 = mutableLiveData7.asLiveData()

    // BTW
    // We could also expose getLiveData8() method, but liveData is a state not an action.

    // Solution 9
    // This does not create backing field for the property
    // (more optimised but still Solution 7 is easier to use)
    private val _liveData9 = MutableLiveData<State>()
    val liveData9 get() = _liveData9 as LiveData<State>
}
```

Comment: I really like solution #5. Unfortunately can't use it yet in Android. BTW I think the `this::_liveData5` can actually be just `liveData5`

Comment: Nope, it cant. Somehow the `this::` is needed

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a util function for this logic:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

fun <T> immutable(data: MutableLiveData<T>): Immutable<T> {
    return Immutable(data)
}

class Immutable<T>(private val data: MutableLiveData<T>) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): LiveData<T> {
        return data
    }
}
```

Then you can use in any of your ViewModel as:

```
private val _counter: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()    
val counter: LiveData<Int> by immutable(_counter)
```

or in short:

```
private val _counter = MutableLiveData<Int>()    
val counter by immutable(_counter)
```